# Uninitialized constant error in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following namespaces ApiController

```rb
class Api::ApiController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, 
  if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.content_type == 'application/json' }
  
  before_action :authenticate

  attr_reader :current_user

  private

    def authenticate

      @current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
      render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401 unless @current_user

    end
    
end
```

On `AuthorizeApiRequest.call`, Rails complains that:

> uninitialized constant Api::ApiController::AuthorizeApiRequest

My AuthorizeApiRequest class is defined under app/commands:

```rb
class AuthorizeApiRequest
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(headers = {})
    @headers = headers
  end

  def call
    user
  end

  private

  attr_reader :headers

  def user
    @user ||= User.find(decoded_auth_token[:user_id]) if decoded_auth_token
    @user || errors.add(:token, 'Invalid token') && nil
  end

  def decoded_auth_token
    @decoded_auth_token ||= JsonWebToken.decode(http_auth_header)
  end

  def http_auth_header
    if headers['Authorization'].present?
      return headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
    else
      errors.add(:token, 'Missing token')
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

So it seems to not allow me to call `AuthorizeApiRequest.call` without added namespace to front. How to fix?

Comment: Try doing it using `::AuthorizeApiRequest.call`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `app/commands` folder doesn't seem to be loaded into Rails at boot.

You need to include your `app/commands` in your autoload paths for this to work or require the file manually in your controller.

See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths